# How do I call a method of same name from an enclosing outer class as the one being implemented in an anonymous class?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I am implementing an interface using an anonymous class that returns a pre-defined folder path as a string and requires a trailing slash. The enclosing object's class implements this already as `getDataFolder()` but returns a `File` object. This is fine except for the fact that the method I'm implementing has the same name...

If I implement it like this then I get a stackoverflow error as the implemented method tries to call itself rather than the outer class method.

```
resourceManager = new PluginResourceManager(this) {
   @Override
   public String getDataFolder()
      throws IOException
   {
      return getDataFolder() + java.io.File.separator;
   }
};
```

The method from the outer class is in scope but is not directly inherited by the anonymous class so I can't simply use `super` here.

How do I explicitly invoke the method I want from the outer class of this anonymous inner class method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parent method"? If you could provide a [mcve], that would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Do you mean OuterClass.this?

Comment: I realized after I had written this that I was using the wrong terms and have corrected this in an edit. It is a method from the enclosing outer class that I am trying to call and not a method from a parent class of the anonymous class (which is itself an interface) that I am defining inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method in the enclosing class is non-static, then call it like this:

```
resourceManager = new PluginResourceManager(this) {
   @Override
   public String getDataFolder()
      throws IOException
   {
      return EnclosingClassName.this.getDataFolder() + java.io.File.separator;
   }
};
```

If the method is static, then a little simpler:

```
resourceManager = new PluginResourceManager(this) {
   @Override
   public String getDataFolder()
      throws IOException
   {
      return EnclosingClassName.getDataFolder() + java.io.File.separator;
   }
};
```